# magnifier glass app, on fingertip only

Tags: applications, zooming

I am looking for an app (maybe it never existed and I imagined it), but it is a screen magnifier that only magnifies a small circle around your fingertip, like the equivalent of a 5 letter word, ideal for magnifying specific words or areas of your screen, I think I saw it once (on iphone maybe?), you just need to keep your fingertip on screen for about 2 seconds then a small circle appears above your fingertip magnifying anything under it, and you can move it all around your screen, and disappears when you lift your finger, is there such thing?

There is the triple TAP but it zooms the whole screen and I do not want that.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are most likely to have seen what you are describing on an iPhone, however there is a similar function available as of Android 9.

You can use the Magnifier Widget on a piece of text by highlighting it and dragging the selection handle as shown on [this](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/magnifier) page.

You can drag the handle around to magnify any of the text on-screen, one downside though is that the magnifier will 'snap' to each line of text which can take a little getting used to.